# Making a JList scroll to the end of it's elements

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am using the following code to scroll to the end of a JList. I use it when I setVisible on the window containing the JList and when I add items to the JList.

```
int lastIndex = getMyList().getModel().getSize() - 1;

if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    getMyList().ensureIndexIsVisible(lastIndex);
}
```

The problem is that upon calling setVisible for the first time the JList scrolls up a couple of items for no apparent reason. If I then call setVisible(false) followed by a call to setVisible(true) the JList gets scrolled to the bottom like it is supposed to be. One thing I noticed was that the moment I open a window some of it's components seem to get re-arranged in a fraction of a second. So Im guessing the problem could be down to that.

So I pressed 'print screen' when I opened one of these windows and you can see that when the window is initially opened the components at the bottom of it aren't even visible (the emoticons and the buttons). Here's what the window looks like when it is 'fully open', and also and image of what it looks like for a fraction of a second just before it is fully open.

**How the window looks once it is opened (you can see the scrollbar is not at the bottom)**
[image]

**How the window looks when I screenshot it as it is opening after a call to setVisible()**
[image]

So anyone know why the layout is changing as the window is opening and how I can get my JList to scroll to the bottom when it first opens?

Answer (score 6):

Try to envelope the `ensureIndexIsVisible()` call in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Comment: @csss works for me, no idea, edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)  +1

Comment: Hmmm, Ive narrowed it down to using html in jlabels in the list. If the text in the center spans multiple lines it causes the scrolling to mess up. Don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: @csss just repeating: a) did you try invokelater? (the issue is not being _on_ the EDT, but being _last_ on EDT) b) where's the SSCCE, so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @kleopatra yes, I tried invokeLater. I was actually thinking earlier that you would be one of the only people who would be capable of figuring this out as you seem to know swing better than anyone. I thought it was gonna be difficult to produce a good SSCCE but I have narrowed the problem down to its root so I will be able to post a proper SSCCE now. But I have been coding for 16 hours straight at this stage so I will have to get some sleep first. :-)

Comment: @kleopatra well I was writing out the SSCCE and I started testing my existing code against the SSCCE code and I narrowed the problem down to the actual window JFrame. It turns out that if you select 'Generate Resize code' (I was using this to center the window) in Netbeans Properites/Code and then tick 'Generate Size' it causes the scrollbar to get messed up when using HTML in JList cells. Unticking 'Generate Size' fixes the problem...so many hours down the drain getting to the bottom of this problem.